# Gradle build suddenly fails saying 'Could not get unknown property 'testInstrum'...'

Tags: android, gradle, build, config

Yesterday I pushed an app to the PLayStore for publishing...this morning I try to build my project and suddenly Gradle build fails saying:

```
Could not get unknown property 'testInstrum' for DefaultConfig_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null, minSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=26, mCodename='null'}, targetSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=28, mCodename='null'}, renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null, renderscriptSupportModeBlasEnabled=null, renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=2, versionName=1.0, applicationId=com.foodhat.app, testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=null, testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={}, testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}, mWearAppUnbundled=null} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DefaultConfig.
```

here are some facts of my Gradle file:

```
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.foodhat.app"
      minSdkVersion 26
      targetSdkVersion 28
      versionCode 2
      versionName "1.0"
      testInstrum
      entationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

What is the Problem here and how to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the extra line after `testInstrum`:

```
   compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.foodhat.app"
      minSdkVersion 26
      targetSdkVersion 28
      versionCode 2
      versionName "1.0"
      testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

You added a new line (probably by accident) after testInstrum and it was considering testIntrum as a property name according to syntax that's why it was giving error.

Comment: Great! didn´t see that...sometimes a programmer hisself introduces bugs and complains about things not working propperly hehe.

Comment: 'sometimes' is an understatement haha